# ¿Cómo utilizar una función con document.getElementById().onclick?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

estoy tratando de mostrar en consola una cadena que se me va a pasar mediante un .txt con formato .json para cargarlo en html.

Bueno en concreto, es que tengo una imagen la que va a tener debajo de ella un título que va a estar en una etiqueta `<h3>` pero internamente como puede cambiar el valor (`.value()`) del título he creado una función a la cual se le pasa como argumento la cadena desde el archivo. Lo que no entiendo es como hacer para que mediante el id que le doy a la etiqueta `<h3>` pueda hacer uso de la función creada.

Esto es lo que tengo momentáneamente en el javascript:

```
function imprime(aux) {
   console.log(aux);
}
```

```
document.getElementById('ttlSECT1_1').onclick = imprime('hola');
```

Quisiera saber como es que se puede utilizar la función al manipular el javascript y antes de pasarle el objeto desde .json ya que después talvez le agregue más operaciones a la función en caso de que se necesite.

Algún consejo?

Comment: Creo o entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es mostrar en la etiqueta h3 lo que te genere la función?

Comment: No precisamente ya que en la etiqueta cuando doy click quiero ver en consola lo que la cadena tiene en el momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de usar el GlobalEventHandler `.onclick`, al igual que con `addEventListener` (que es la forma recomendada), es pasando el nombre de una función o la función anónima, pero para llamar una función **con parámetros** tiene que hacerse dentro de una función anónima:

```js
function imprime(aux) {
  console.log(aux);
}

const elemento = document.getElementById('ttlSECT1_1').onclick = () => imprime("Hola");
```

```html
<button id="ttlSECT1_1">
click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que haces con `onclick` es ejecutar una función tras pulsar un elemento, puedes usar cualquier función que le necesites dar.

Puedes guardar el elemento en una variable y darle toda la funcionalidad que te apetezca.

```js
var mih3 = document.getElementById('myh3')
mih3.onmouseenter = function() { 
  this.style.background = "black";
  this.style.color = "white";
}
mih3.onclick = function(){ this.innerHTML = "Pulsa aquí" }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="myh3">Botón</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando el código que tienes la respuesta sería como esto:

```
<h3 onclick="imprime()">Mostrar</h3>
```

De manera que, cuando des click a la Etiqueta, te mostrará en consola.